# Cómo poner la ruta en BLADE para acceder al Layout

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Necesito que en la vista  ***insertarPregunta.blade.php*** tenga la plantilla ***plantillaFormulario.blade.php***, pero como la ruta va con puntos y está en un nivel superior del directorio, no se cómo poner la ruta.

Esto funcionaría si el directorio layouts estuviese al mismo nivel (no es el caso):

```
@extends("layouts.plantillaFormulario")
```

Algo así en el caso que necesito mostrado en la imagen:

```
@extends("../layouts.plantillaFormulario")
```

(pero no funciona)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo se debe poner la ruta?

Comment: No es necesario que layouts esté en el mismo nivel del directorio privado. Tal como lo tienes escrito debe funcionar, solo debe estar entre comillas simples ''.

Answer (score 0):

Te comento que la función `extends()` de Laravel siempre comenzará a partir de `resources/views/` independientemente de donde estés, así que no es necesario los `...` y quedaría así:

```
@extends("layouts.plantillaFormulario")
```

Tampoco importa si está con comillas simples o con dobles, de cualquier forma debe de funcionar.

Answer (score -1):

La directiva `@extends()` de Blade toma como parámetro la ruta de un layout, tomando como base **siempre** o al menos normalmente el directorio de vistas que en el caso de Laravel 5.8+ será `resources/views`.

En ese orden de ideas y teniendo en cuenta que la ruta no es relativa con respecto a la vista en la que se está usando, debería funcionar perfectamente la primera sintaxis que muestras:

```
@extends('layouts.plantillaFormulario')
```

Documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#extending-a-layout

Comment: ¿Y el voto negativo? Quisiera ver una mejor repuesta que la mía entonces